# How to enable Postman's Newman verbose output? (to show request's body)

Tags: postman

When running a collection test with Newman, I'd like it to display the request body sent, to have a more detailed record of the test (and making sure the environment variables were replaced correctly).

I checked the Newman command line options [at the project documentation](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#commandline-options) and found nothing, and the -O option described [in this old issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/311) is not working.

I'd like to know how to activate the verbose output.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a popular feature request that has been documented at GitHub [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/712)

As a workaround, you can add this to the post-request each test you want to log:

```
tests["[INFO] Request: " + JSON.stringify(request)] = true;
tests["[INFO] Response: " + responseBody] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

try the `--verbose` [option](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options). This is an example output:

```
GET http://myapp:8080/b/api/v1/0 
 
  401 Unauthorized ★ 59ms time ★ 290B↑ 367B↓ size ★ 8↑ 5↓ headers ★ 0 cookies
  ┌ ↓ application/json ★ text ★ json ★ utf8 ★ 193B
  │ {"path":"http://myapp:8080/b/api/v1/0","message":"401 Unauthorized from POST http:
  │ //myotherapp:8080/v1/auth/user","timestamp":"2022-03-23
  │ T10:11:31.133683","status":401}
  └
  prepare   wait    dns-lookup   tcp-handshake   transfer-start   download   process   total 
  1ms       284µs   (cache)      (cache)         56ms             1ms        51µs      59ms
```